# JDK 7 on mac 10.6.2 (32bits)

Tags: snow-leopard

I want to install JDK version 7 on my mac Snow leopard 10.6.2 (32bits).
 How can I do it ? Pleas give me some help ? is it possible or not ?

Comment: You may have to consider using a Virtual Machine (VMWare, Virtual Box) and use another OS on it?

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 and Java 8 is only available in a 64-bit version on OS X, and therefor it can only be installed on a 64-bit Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is only supporting Java 7 on Mac OS X 10.7 and above.

However, there is a possible solution/answer on our sister site [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024322).

Or visit Adobe help [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installation-problems-flash-player-mac.html#Flash_Player_for_Safari).

But, I am not sure it is possible at all on 32 bit, so consider if your system [can support 64 bit.](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3770)

Answer (score -1):

I have tested this solution, and when I install jdk version 7, the installation is failed. And when I go into */Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_72/Contents/Home/bin/java* in order to run java it return **Bad CPU type in executable**.

Is the problem because I have a mac with 32bits?

Comment: Please do not use answers for follow-up questions; edit your original question instead or if a new one arises, ask a new one. In this case though, your OS version is simply not supported.